# How do I add Debug Breakpoints to lines displayed in a "Find Results" window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

In Visual Studio 2005-2015 it is possible to find all lines containing certain references and display them in a "Find Results" window.

Now that these result lines are displayed, is there any keyboard shortcut that would allow adding debug breakpoints to all of them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***This answer does not work for Visual Studio 2015 or later. A more recent answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061627/how-do-i-add-debug-breakpoints-to-lines-displayed-in-a-find-results-window-in?rq=1).***

You can do this fairly easily with a Visual Studio macro.  Within Visual Studio, hit Alt-F11 to open the Macro IDE and add a new module by right-clicking on MyMacros and selecting Add|Add Module...

Paste the following in the source editor:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module CustomMacros
    Sub BreakpointFindResults()
        Dim findResultsWindow As Window = DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindFindResults1)

        Dim selection As TextSelection
        selection = findResultsWindow.Selection
        selection.SelectAll()

        Dim findResultsReader As New StringReader(selection.Text)
        Dim findResult As String = findResultsReader.ReadLine()

        Dim findResultRegex As New Regex("(?<Path>.*?)\((?<LineNumber>\d+)\):")

        While Not findResult Is Nothing
            Dim findResultMatch As Match = findResultRegex.Match(findResult)

            If findResultMatch.Success Then
                Dim path As String = findResultMatch.Groups.Item("Path").Value
                Dim lineNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(findResultMatch.Groups.Item("LineNumber").Value)

                Try
                    DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", path, lineNumber)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' breakpoints can't be added everywhere
                End Try
            End If

            findResult = findResultsReader.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Sub
End Module
```

This example uses the results in the "Find Results 1" window; you might want to create an individual shortcut for each result window.

You can create a keyboard shortcut by going to Tools|Options... and selecting **Keyboard** under the **Environment** section in the navigation on the left.  Select your macro and assign any shortcut you like.

You can also add your macro to a menu or toolbar by going to Tools|Customize... and selecting the **Macros** section in the navigation on the left.  Once you locate your macro in the list, you can drag it to any menu or toolbar, where it its text or icon can be customized to whatever you want.

Comment: Is this still possible? I'm not sure what hitting alt F11 is supposed to bring up and cannot find a Macro window to go to in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @SweetTomato This answer is almost 10 years old.  I haven't used any variant of Visual Studio in over 5 years, but I doubt any of this is relevant anymore.

Comment: I think the new macros require .js

Answer (score 3):

If you can search for the word exactly, you can use a pair of keyboard shortcuts to do it quickly.

Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Keyboard

- Edit.GoToFindResults1NextLocation
- EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.Breakpoint.InsertBreakpoint

Assign them to Control+Alt+F11 and F10 and you can go through all the results very quickly.  I haven't found a shortcut for going to the next reference however.

Comment: F3 and F9 do this without having to re-assign any shortcuts.

Comment: F3 goes to the next result in the current panel, not the next line in Find Results. It's possible to use F3 in the Find Results pane but you also need to hit Enter and tab between the code & results panes. This answer saves a lot of keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

I needed something similar to disable all breakpoints and place a breakpoint on every "Catch ex as Exception". However, I expanded this a little so it will place a breakpoint at every occurance of the string you have selected. All you need to do with this is highlight the string you want to have a breakpoint on and run the macro.

```
 Sub BreakPointAtString()

    Try
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.DisableAllBreakpoints")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Dim tsSelection As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.text
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.selectall()
    Dim AllText As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text

    Dim findResultsReader As New StringReader(AllText)
    Dim findResult As String = findResultsReader.ReadLine()
    Dim lineNum As Integer = 1

    Do Until findResultsReader.Peek = -1
        lineNum += 1
        findResult = findResultsReader.ReadLine()
        If Trim(findResult) = Trim(tsSelection) Then
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.GotoLine(lineNum)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.ToggleBreakpoint")
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Paul, thanks a lot, but I have the following error (message box), may be I need to restart my PC:

```
Error
---------------------------
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I would propose the following solution that's very simple but it works for me

```
Sub BreakPointsFromSearch()
    Dim n As Integer = InputBox("Enter the number of search results")

    For i = 1 To n
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToNextLocation")
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.ToggleBreakpoint")            
    Next
End Sub
```