# How to break whenever a class is entered

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-construction, breakpoints

I've read the thread [break whenever a file(or class) is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250576/break-whenever-a-file-or-class-is-entered). And I now understood the basic mechanism how to automatically set breakpoints in the classes. However, the solution that thread provided is focused on .net framework. My problem is how to deal with it in standard C++. We use vc 10 compiler on windows 7 platform.

Besides, we prefer methods which do not need recompile when we rechoose the class which we want to inspect since it is a huge project and recompilation takes a lot of time.

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from the IDE:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/09/10/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The answer Emile Cormier gives is a good solution. When I try to add a breakpoint "Stack::* " as the link says, I found there is no red point on the left of code lines until I start debugging the program. After stopping the program, the red points disappear, but the break point window will keep track of every breakpoint and you can turn to the code by double clicking the breakpoint in the breakpoint window.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can only set memory breakpoints (break whenever the contents of a certain memory address is read/written) and then manual breakpoints (break on a certain line of code).

Your best bet may be to set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function call(s) you want to debug.