# Set breakpoint on a class in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Is there a way to place a Breakpoint on a class, so that whenever control reaches any field, property or method of that class, execution breaks?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250576/break-whenever-a-file-or-class-is-entered (macro)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750967/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-every-method-in-vs2010 (OzCode)

Comment: See https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b4aaf8aa-58ab-40a1-b45c-feb3efc94e1e (Breakpoint Generator extension)

Answer (score 0):

Just place the breakpoint at the Constructor of the class, or at a specific method.

Comment: The point is that I DO NOT want to place a breakpoint at every possible place in my class. I have a huge class (5000 LOC+) and I want to know when control hits this class.