# How do I add Debug Breakpoints to lines displayed in a “Find Results” window in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This question was answered before for a previous version of Visual Studio (VS). The offered solutions involved macros, which are no longer available in VS 2015. Could I get a solution for VS 2015?

I would like to do a "find all" in VS and put a debug-breakpoint on every line with a find match.

Link to previous question asked by Noah:
[How do I add Debug Breakpoints to lines displayed in a "Find Results" window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063/how-do-i-add-debug-breakpoints-to-lines-displayed-in-a-find-results-window-in)

Comment: Please add a link to the previous answer for reference.

Comment: You should be able to run an old macro in VS 2015 with Visual Commander.

Comment: I have added the link to the previous question.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov The old macro was not running properly in Visual Commander and Macros For Visual Studio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've converted the old macro to a VB command in [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) (by adding explicit namespaces to classes):

```
Public Class C
    Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand

    Sub Run(DTE As EnvDTE80.DTE2, package As Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package) Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand.Run
        Dim findResultsWindow As EnvDTE.Window = DTE.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindFindResults1)

        Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection
        selection = findResultsWindow.Selection
        selection.SelectAll()

        Dim findResultsReader As New System.IO.StringReader(selection.Text)
        Dim findResult As String = findResultsReader.ReadLine()

        Dim findResultRegex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<Path>.*?)\((?<LineNumber>\d+)\):")

        While Not findResult Is Nothing
            Dim findResultMatch As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = findResultRegex.Match(findResult)

            If findResultMatch.Success Then
                Dim path As String = findResultMatch.Groups.Item("Path").Value
                Dim lineNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(findResultMatch.Groups.Item("LineNumber").Value)

                Try
                    DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", path, lineNumber)
                Catch ex As System.Exception
                    ' breakpoints can't be added everywhere
                End Try
            End If

            findResult = findResultsReader.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It works and is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Demodave I've rechecked and it works for me in VS 2019 v16.4.2.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I also cant seem to make it work for vs2019. I tried to debug it but I am not super familiar with VB. From what I found was that findResult was completely empty when getting to the loop. Do you happen to have any thing special in your version? I also have Professional 16.4.2.

Comment: @Demodave i found the issue. The script focuses on the Find Results 1 Window. Most likely when you use the Find All you have the result option to 
List Results in:
Find results table

When the script only reads from Find Results 1 window.

Is there any way to change the script to the table? Its easier to read after all. Tried to look into the EnvDTE but cant seem to find the window as theres no documentation for 2019.

Comment: @Demodave Yes, VS now uses new find result controls that don't support extensibility.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov So does this script can't be used or altered?

Comment: @Demodave I'm not aware how to provide the required functionality with the new VS search controls.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [JetBrains Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and use one of Reharper's search commands, you can do this directly from Resharper's Find Results window (different from VS Find Results).

Example:

Resharper > Navigate > Go to Text... (Ctrl+T,T,T if using Resharper key map)

And then in Find Results (Resharper), right click any node or container in the tree view and choose "Set Breakpoint."  This sets a breakpoint on all sub-nodes.

[image]

Reference:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/12/04/debugger-features-resharper/