# Can I set breakpoint to constructors of all the classes in my code?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I can set breakpoint to all the functions of particular class as,

```
ClassName::*
```

Is it possible to set breakpoint to all the constructors in the code, something like,

```
*::Constructor //any particular keyword
```

I am able to set breakpoint using Visual Studio Macros using macro suggested in answer to '[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063/how-do-i-add-debug-breakpoints-to-lines-displayed-in-a-find-results-window-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)'.

Comment: @JackZhai No I am finding solution.

Answer (score 1):

I test it in my side using constructors, it doesn't work. I often use the function breakpoint or the Find Combo box and Press F9 manually, like you said that set breakpoint to all the functions of particular class works well, but not the second way for constructors.

A workaround is that you could use certain extension tool like Breakpoint Generator, even if it just help you add breakpoints for the public methods, but it really could help developers add breakpoints easily and conveniently:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b4aaf8aa-58ab-40a1-b45c-feb3efc94e1e

Of course, I also help you submit a feature request here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16245607-is-it-possible-to-set-breakpoint-to-all-the-constr.
Maybe certain VS extension experts could also provide a good path for this issue.